# Can Maven Site add test method names to the class documentation?

Tags: java, maven, junit, javadoc, maven-site-plugin

I have a class Something and a JUnit test class TestSomething.

How can I add the test method names of TestSomething to the documentation of Something?

Comment: JavaDoc or what are you talking about? Which documentation?

Comment: Yes, this is JavaDoc. We use "mvn site" to build JavaDoc. I want to add test method names instead of just text, because tests will fail if they are wrong. Text will just mislead the reader and waste time.

Answer (score 0):

you can run javadoc for test classes too: see tes-javadoc goal http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/test-javadoc-mojo.html